# how to parse values returned by one contract into another?

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-design, interfaces

I've two contracts deployed one is `UserRegistration` and another is `Exam`

I've `getUser(uint id)` method to fetch data of particular user using `users` mapping,

```
function getUser(uint _id) public constant returns(uint,string,string,uint,uint) {

  User memory c = users[_id];

  return(
  c.id,
  c.name,
  c.class,
  c.age,
  c.pincode);
}
```

Now, I've another contract `Exam` in which I want to call `getUser()` function from `UserRegistration` contract so, I've done it like this,

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract UserRegistration
{
    function getUserCount() public returns(uint);
    function getUser(uint) public returns(uint,string,string,uint,uint);
}

contract Exam
{
    address private addrUsr;
    uint public count;
    UserRegistration r;
    constructor(address _addrUsr)
    {
        addrUsr=_addrUsr;
        r = UserRegistration(addrUsr);
    }

    function updateCount() public {

        count=r.getUserCount();
    }

    function getUserData(uint _id) public
    {
        //WHAT to do HERE//;
    }       

}
```

But, how to parse the values returned by `getUser()` function into `getUserData()` so that if I call `getUserData()` function it should return all the values returned by `getUser()`, and as the values returned by `getUser()` function are of different data type I can't store them in an array.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're using `constant` in the registry. If that's right for the compiler you're using, stick with that, otherwise `view` for a newer compiler.

In any case, use it in both:

You should add `view` to the getter functions in *both* contracts.

```
function getUserData(uint _id) public view returns (uint,string,string,uint,uint) { // or constant
    //WHAT to do HERE//
    uint id;
    string name;
    string class;
    uint age;
    uint pincode;

    (id, name, class, age, pincode) = r.getUser(_id);

    return(id, name, class, age, pincode);
}
```

Hope it helps.